# This expression is not callable on custom hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, shopify

I'm trying to create a custom hook to make a POST call but I get a problem when trying to call the `mutate` function. Here's my code.

My custom hook:
[image]

This is how I'm trying to call it:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the error message when you hover over `mutate` (with squiggly line) ?

Comment: Also please don't post screen grabs. Paste textual code

Comment: This expression is not callable.

Not all constituents of type '((selectedResources: string[]) => void) | { data: VerificationState; isLoading: boolean; error: null; }' are callable.
    Type '{ data: VerificationState; isLoading: boolean; error: null; }' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

Comment: VerificationState is an enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was just a TypeScript error :(

Have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35423) for more info